# Computing expected values of a random variable, where we only have the moment generating function

Tags: probability, moment-generating-functions, balls-in-bins

This is problem 37 from chapter 4 of Bertsekas and Tsitsiklis's *Introduction to Probability*.

The problem appears to come down to a filling of $n$ bins with $k$ objects and asking for the expected number of filled bins.

I computed the expected value of $X_{1}$, the random variable that is 0 if the first bin is empty and 1 if the first bin has at least one ball.

The complement of this event is for all the balls to land in the remaining $n-1$ bins. So the probability of the complement event is $p = (\frac{n-1}{n})^k$, implying that:

$$P_{X_{1}} = 1 - \left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^{k}$$

By linearity of expectation, the expected number of filled bins is the above probability (also the expectation) times $n$. I think this is correct. I checked on a few examples, but I might have made a mistake here.

The problem I have is that $k$ is defined by a random variable, and I only have the moment generating function $M_{K}(s)$. The expected value should be given in terms of $M_{K}(\cdot)$.

From the moment generating function, I know that I can compute expected values of moments of $K$, e.g., $\mathbb{E}[K]$ and $\mathbb{E}[K^{2}]$, but I am at a loss on how to merge that with the expected number of filled bins determined above.

What's the right approach here?

Comment: Let $X$ be the number of filled bins. What you have worked out is $\mathbb E[X\mid K=k]$, i.e. the expected value of $X$ *conditional* on $K=k$. You might know (prove it!) that $\mathbb E[X]=\mathbb E[\mathbb E[X\mid K]]$. Recall also that you can derive the probability masses $\mathbb P(K=k)$ from the generating function.

Comment: Ah, the Law of Iterated Expectations. Let me take try this tack. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seek $\mathsf E(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i)$ where $X_i$ is the indicator that bin $i$ is not empty, when you have $n$ bins and a random number of balls, $K$, and knowing the moment generating function for that.

We might assume the indicators are *identically distributed*, and with $\mathsf E(X_1\mid K)=1-(1-1/n)^K$ by the reasoning you gave (that each ball selects a bin independently and without bias).

Combining this with the Linearity of Expectation, with the Law of Total Expectation (aka the Law of Iterated Expectation), as @jlammy suggested, we begin with:

$$\begin{align}\mathsf E({\textstyle\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}) &= n\,\mathsf E(X_1)\\ &= n\,\mathsf E(\mathsf E(X_1\mid K))\\[1ex] &=n\,\mathsf E(1-(1-1/n)^K)\\[1ex] &= n\,(1-\mathsf E((1-1/n)^K))\\[1ex]&~~\vdots\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $X_i$ be the indicator variable for whether the $i$th bin is filled. Notice that the $X_i$'s are identically distributed. As you correctly point out, $X_i \sim Bern(p)$ with $p = 1 - \left( \frac{n-1}{n} \right)^k$. The expected number of bins filled is then given by $E(X_1 + \ldots + X_n)$. Can you take it from there?

Comment: So, I didn't have a problem with this part as I noted in my post, due to linearity of expectation. What I was having trouble with is taking that value and doing something with it in the context of an arbitrary moment generating function. But maybe what you're suggesting is what jlammy is suggesting in comments.